# Can I Delete The pref_header.xml From SettingsActivity And Code in pref_general.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-settings

Good day, I' having a problem with the SettingActivity.
The pref_header.xml is called first. And when I clicked one of them they
will direct me to their pref_layout (notification, sync data) .xml . Which I find annoying.

**My problem is, is it ok to delete the pref_header.xml?
And just do the programming directly in pref_general.xml?**
I'm trying to achieved the SettingActivity as shown below.

[image: Settings Activity]

Comment: are you able to answer your own question now?

Comment: I presume you were trying to skip "<preference-headers..." and go directly to "<PreferenceScreen..."